# Is a nested Builder class really necessary as described in Effective Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

So, in the famous **Effective Java** book, it introduces a **Builder pattern** where you can have an inner static Builder class to instantiate a class. The book suggests the following design of a class:

```
public class Example {
    private int a;
    private int b;

    public static class Builder() {
        private int a;
        private int b;

        public Builder a(int a) {
            this.a = a;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder b(int b) {
            this.b = b;
            return this;
        }

        public Example build() {
            return new Example(this);    
        }
    }

    private Example(Builder builder) {
        this.a = builder.a;
        this.b = builder.b;
    }
}
```

However I have failed to understand **why do we really need an inner `Builder class`?** The above code have duplicate lines for field declarations (int a, b), this would become relatively messy if we had more fields.

Why not just get rid of the `Builder` class, and let `Example` class take on all the `set` methods that were in `Builder` class?

So to instantiate `Example`, it would become `Example e = new Example().a(3).b.(3);` instead of `Example e = new Example.Builder.a(3).b(3).build();`

---

NOTE: The book suggests this pattern for classes that have a long list of parameters to be set.

Comment: It's most useful for producing immutable objects.

Comment: In some cases of complicated initialization, your values should already be set. Also, having `a()` and `b()` methods make the `Example` object mutable.

Comment: Builder is not necessary for this case, and in fact makes the code far more verbose.

Comment: @shmosel EpicPandaForce So I guess this pattern is mainly to support immutable classes. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Builder is a pattern for the construction of *complex* objects. I wouldn't count your example as complex; indeed, the builder adds an awful lot of unnecessary code, rather than just using constructor parameters.

There are a few reasons why you'd want to use a builder:

- To construct complex immutable objects. Immutable objects need to have final (or logically final) fields, so they must be set at construction time.

  Let's say that you have N fields, but you only want to explicitly set some of them in certain use cases. You would need up to 2^N constructors to cover all of the cases - known as "telescoping", since the length of the parameter list gets longer and longer. The builder allows you to model optional parameters: if you don't want to set that parameter, don't call that setter method.
- To allow self-documentation of the parameters' meaning. By naming the setter methods appropriately, you can see what the values mean at a glance.

  It also helps to verify that you are not accidentally reversing parameters of the same type, since you can see what each value is used for.

Comment: Good point about naming method naming allowing for inferring the meaning of the parameter.

Comment: Thanks Andy, however am I correct in saying that your second point could be achieved without a builder pattern as well? (with normal setters) So essentially, the builder pattern is useful only when I want my class to be immutable?

Comment: I mean, one could specify "Builder-like" set methods to a class (which achieves your second point), but that'll then make the class mutable. So The builder pattern is beneficial **only** if I want my class to be **immutable** with the benefit of your second point.

Comment: It can. Just don't underestimate the value of immutability. If you like EJ quotes, there is another along the lines of "make classes immutable unless necessary". Also, note that mutable classes might be "partially immutable", i.e. there are some properties that are immutable, and must be set at construction time.

Comment: I am actually reading that part of the book tonight :). Thanks for the clarification Andy. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If the fields in the outer class are final, then the builder is necessary if you want to incrementally specify parameter values, as all fields must be initialized in the constructor.

The builder inner class allows fields to be initialized incrementally.

As others have pointed out, this applies to immutable objects as well.  The fields don't need to be final; they effectively will be if no setters are supplied in the outer class.

The builder can possibly accumulate the parameters more efficiently than direct construction.  Consider the `StringBuilder`.  It allocates a temporary buffer to accumulate partial results.  The "build" operation in its case is `toString()`.

Finally, there could be things you just can't do in the constructor of a class.  If you need to pass a value to a super constructor, but that value is not part of the arguments to your constructor, it may not be possible to, since you must call `super()` first, and you might not be able to create the argument(s) as a simple expression inside the `super(...)` call.  The BoxLayout comes to mind.  You pass the `JPanel` to the `BoxLayout` constructor.  You pass the layout to the `JPanel` constructor.  Chicken and egg.  And this code is not allowed, because `this` is not yet constructed.

```
class X extends JPanel {
    X() {
        super( new BoxLayout(this) );   // Error: Cannot use "this" yet
    }
}
```

Fortunately, a `JPanel` is not immutable; you can set the layout after construction.

Comment: No: if the fields in the outer class are final, you could provide them via explicit constructor parameters.

Comment: @AndyTurner - sorry, I meant for incremental construction.  I'll edit to make clearer.

Comment: @AndyTurner You are correct, however the book suggests this pattern is only beneficial for those objects that have loooong list of parameters that cannot simply be passed as constructor parameters. Sorry about the confusion, I should have made it clear in the question

Comment: @JoelMin, the long number of parameters is another good reason, especially when some parameters are optional. There is nothing worse than a constructor with 10 parameters, some of which may be null.

Comment: Thanks guys. So I guess the key benefit is that it allows **flexible instantiation with immutable objects**. So essentially, if I do not wish to make my class immutable I would not need to use this pattern

Answer (score 1):

The rationale is for complicated classes. Notice that the `Builder` object returns itself, so one can do chaining, such as:

```
Example exp = Example.Builder().a(5).b(10).build();
```

Apache uses this approach in some cases to allow the incremental setting of various values. It also allows the `.build()` method to do some checking of all of the correct values to make an object if desired.

Comment: Thank you Kevin, that was insightful, +1!